# When I run a program in GDB, how does GDB show me the program's virtual address?

Tags: c, debugging, process, gdb

I compiled a simple code and I runned it by GDB.

When I run my simple program in GDB, GDB shows me the program's virtual address (which is defined in my program's executable object file) to me.

GDB is a program too. so GDB have its own virtual address. Because GDB have its own virtual address, when GDB mmap my simple program to gain virtual address, my simple program will have different virtual address in the GDB's virtual address space.

But GDB doesn't show me that address. Instead, GDB show me my simple program's virtual address which defined in my simple program's executable object file.

How did this happen? Does GDB have virtual to virtual address table?

Comment: You may find the three-part series [How debuggers work](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/23/how-debuggers-work-part-1) helpful.

Comment: oh, thank you. that document helped me.

Comment: no, your program doesn't get a different virtual address space when attached into gdb's own address space.  Your program has no means of knowing it is being debugged, as gdb launches your program with the standard linux tools available.  It continues to have the same virtual address it had before gdb was aware of it.  GDB is the program that converts the attached process addresses (in its own virtual address space) into the attached process' virtual address space, so you have the proper addresses referred as if no gdb was involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gdb is a program too. so gdb have its own virtual address. because gdb have its own virtual address, when gdb run my simple program, my simple program will have different virtual address in the gdb's virtual address space.

You are *very* confused.

On any modern OS, gdb and your program run in *different* (virtual) address spaces, which have nothing to do with each other, and can overlap in arbitrary ways.

For a non-position-independent executable, both GDB and your program will load at the virtual address they were linked to be loaded at. You can see that address as the `VirtAddr` of the first `PT_LOAD` segment in `readelf -l /path/to/a.out` output. On Linux/x86_64, that address is (by default) `0x400000`.

For a position-independent executable, the address of the first `PT_LOAD` segment is usually 0, and the executable is relocated.

If both your binary and GDB are PIE, they'll both be relocated, but again they do not share the address space, and thus can be relocated to the exact same (virtual) address.

Comment: umm thanks for answering. but i know that each program has its own address. suggest there is a program A.  when my shell runs gdb, shell will fork another process and exec gdb. Then, gdb will mmap 'A' on its own virtual address area. Of course, A's base area will be changed compared to its virtual address wrote on A's executable object file.

Comment: . for example, symbol main's virtual address is 0x10cfc in the A's executable object file. In gdb program, I can make break point at 0x10cfc(main). but in gdb process, main will not exist in 0x10cfc. I have a question in here. how can gdb know that 0x10cfc is main?     i supposed my computer is raspberry pi 3(32bit)

Comment: exactly you are right. they don't share address. but if gdb want to point to some address of my simple program  'A',  gdb will 'mmap' program 'A' to gain virtual address maybe.